# Adding compile sources to Xcode Unit Tests (Application vs Logic)

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

It seems that Logic tests require that I add application files (.m and .h) to the compile target of the test along with the test .m files. I think that this is because Application tests actually load the app side by side with the tests but I am not sure.

Is the bundle loader 'the difference' between Application and Logic tests? I am not talking about why to use them but the distinction between how they work and what they do.

Comment: Yes it boils down to the bundle loader. In the case of 'application tests' the symbolicated, compiled classes from the main bundle (along with all of the resources) are used to run the tests. 

Logic tests run in their own separate bundle. . . Comment because not quite good enough to be an answer, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here you can find a nice description of the tests, with what they do and how they differ.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/01-Unit-Test_Overview/overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH2-SW1) Also, in the next section [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH3-SW1), you can read about how to set them up, which reveals the technical differences between them. As you suggested, loading the app bundle seems to make the difference.

Edit: Seems that the links above no longer work, I found a legacy document here: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/UnitTesting.pdf

Comment: These links, they are dead.

Comment: I added a link to the legacy document.